# What does WriteBuffer(Longword, SizeOf(Longword)) do?

Tags: delphi

I'm a C# guy and I am trying to understand a code snippet in Delphi language, while something like `Stream.ReadBuffer(Value, SizeOf(Value))` makes senses to me that `Value` is filled with data from `Stream`, I do not understand the last line of the following code snippet:

```
procedure TPodBdfStream.LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
... // content suppressed for brevity
var
  Stream: TStream;
  Value: Longword;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  WriteBuffer(Value, SizeOf(Longword));
```

What does `WriteBuffer(Value, SizeOf(Longword));` do since no stream is involved in the call ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a stream involved. It is the `TPodBdfStream` instance that is running this code. You can also think of an implied `Self.WriteBuffer()`.

`WriteBuffer()` writes `Value` to `Self`.

(As Value is not assigned anything it may contain whatever, or maybe you omitted the line)

Comment: "*As Value is not assigned anything it may contain whatever*" - considering the "content suppressed for brevity" comment in the code, it is possible that `Value` actually does have content, but its assignment would not be relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Now that you've explained it, it really makes sense, i.e. it's a class member, thanks!